# Not being available to change user installation in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, android, cloud

I am trying to add new channels to the parse installation of other users using a parse cloud.
This is the Parse Cloud Code:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("subscribeToChannel", function(request, response) {
  var channelName = request.params.channel;
  var ids = request.params.ids;//this is an array of ids to change
  var _ = require("underscore");
  _.each(ids, function(id) {
  // Create a Pointer to this user based on their object id
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.id = id;
    // Need the Master Key to update Installations
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 
    // A user might have more than one Installation
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo("User", user); // Match Installations with a pointer to this User
    query.find({
      success: function(installations){
    for (var i = 0; i < installations.length; i++){
      // Add the channel to all the installations for this user
      installations[i].addUnique("channels", channelName);
    }
    // Save all the installations
    Parse.Object.saveAll(installations, {
      success: function(installations) {
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
      },
      error: function(error) {
    console.error(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

And this is how I set up the first installation for each user:

```
ParseInstallation inst = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
inst.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
```

The array of ids I send is a JSONArray which contains a list of string ids.
The JSONArray gets and iterate correctly.
But no matter how many times I have tried, it just seems not to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error was that I wasn't saving the channel in a correct way.
After long talking with the dev team in Parse I was able to make it happen. Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("subscribeToChannel", function(request, response) {
var channelName = request.params.channel; //Channel the user will be subscribed to
var ids = request.params.ids; //Id of the users
var completed = true;
var size = 0;
var pased = 0;
var loops = 0;
var idStrings = "";
var _ = require("underscore");
if (!channelName) {
response.error("Missing parameter: channel");
return;
}
if (!ids) {
response.error("Missing parameter: ids");
return;
}
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
var user = new Parse.User();
var changedObjects = [];
var pointerArray = [];
_.each(ids, function(id){
pointerArray.push({"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":id});
});

// Need the Master Key to update Installations
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
query.containedIn("User",pointerArray);
query.find({
success: function(installations){
for (var i = 0; i < installations.length; i++){
// Add the channel to all the installations for this user
installations[i].addUnique("channels", channelName); //Add the channel to the installation
changedObjects.push(installations[i]); //Add the installation to be saved later on!
}

//Saving all the installations
Parse.Object.saveAll(changedObjects, { 
success: function(installations) {
response.success();
},
error: function(error) {
// An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
response.error(error);
}
});
},
error: function(error) {
response.error(error);
}
});
});
```

Comment: Hi Javi, how were you able to figure out the current installation for the device ?

Comment: What do you mean? I got help from Parse support (Is that what you asked?)

Comment: I think you have to pass the installationId to the function... Or you should update all installations belong to this user (add an user pointer to the installation object)

Answer (score 1):

I have just found your question, because I am trying to do the same operation, using CloudCode, but it seems is not possible, at least at present.
According to Parse team: "The JavaScript SDK does not currently support modifying Installation objects. Take a look at the iOS, Android or REST Push guide".
Below there is the link:

[parse.com/docs/push_guide#setup/JavaScript](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#setup/JavaScript)

Besides, there are other operations that JavaScript SDK can not do:

1. The JavaScript SDK does not currently support subscribing channels in order to send/receive push notifications
2. The JavaScript SDK does not currently support receiving pushes

But on the other hand, you can send push notifications.
Then, as I am developing a Android native app, I am forced to "mix" ParseClode and "Android code" in order to complete the notification push functionality.

I hope it will helps you

Regards

Comment: Actually I was able to do this, I'll answer my question for everyone to see.